# Calling one command from other in case of using CQRS

Tags: php, cqrs

I'm developing application using CQRS. And I have on case where I'm a little confused.

I have one command CreateUser. Now I have to create command ImportUsers. I guess purposes of those commands are clear. So there are two options:

1. Calling  CreateUser command from ImportUsers command.
2. Make kinda of copy/paste to do all thing from scratch in ImportUsers command.

What's best practice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Althoug I have no hands-on experience with CQRS (have to admit I even had to Google it), I would definitely say option 1. 'Copy-paste code' quite often means 'hard to maintain code'.

Comment: There is something not clear from your architecture. The `CreateUser` command would be processed by a single Aggregate, the User Aggregate. However, the `ImportUsers` command could NOT be processed by a single User Aggregate (because `Users` means more than one User). This suggest that there is also another Aggregate type involved here. What is that other Aggregate type? What are the consistency requirements regarding `ImportUsers` command? Must it be atomic (all users are imported or none)? Could it be eventually consistent (all users are eventually imported)?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I guess If you suggested invlolve new aggregate, that means system will have full consistent and it like my second option? In case of eventually consistent - it's first option.

Comment: dont forget to select an answer when youre satisfied

Answer (score 3):

You are putting your logic in the wrong place, and that’s what’s causing the problems. Commands are meant to be orchestrators of domain logic.  In other words, they call appropriate method(s) in the domain to get their job done, they don’t do it themselves.

The logic to create a single user belongs in a factory that each of these methods calls.  The factory should have a CreateUser method that accepts all data as parameters, or accepts a DTO if there are more than about 5 or so params, which I assume there are.  With a factory to create users, the only difference in the two commands is that the ImportUsers will call the factory CreateUser method in a loop.

Check [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216408/cqrs-commands-and-queries-do-they-belong-in-the-domain) about the idea behind commands.  If you are using DDD, read [Udi Dahan's post](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/) about how all object creations should be in a method on some aggregate somewhere.

Comment: BTW, if your system is message based, or even Event Sourced, the best way for the ImportUsers command to work is put a series of UserCreationRequested events on the queue and let them be handled in the normal way.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Let me show part my command handler. https://pastebin.com/8JZhA2as Because do I really have to use factory there?

Comment: There are several advantages to factories so in general they are a good idea, but I couldn't say you "have to use" a factory.  

The original question mentioned your concern about "copy/paste to do all the thing from scratch".  I inferred that there was a lot of code involved in creating your user.  Copy/pasting basic code for a command is fine - ImportUsers is a different command and should have it's own class and code.  The only significant code you are copy/pasting is the single line User constructor, which should not be a concern.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time :)